# Change echo files to echo folders - PHP

Tags: php, html

How would I display the most recent change in any file in a folder in PHP? I've tried the following PHP/HTML code, and the final table row doesn't work? Any ideas?

```
<?php 
    $lines = file("subjects.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $data = array_map(function($v){
        list($username, $score) = explode(";", $v);
        return ["subject" => $username];
    }, $lines);

    usort($data, function($a, $b){
        if($a["subject"] == $b["subject"])
            return 0;
        return $a["subject"] > $b["subject"] ? 1 : -1;
    });

?>
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>Homework</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,="> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="nav-bar">
        <li>
            <a class="blue" href="/homework/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/homework/subjects">Subjects</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/homework/list">All Homework</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="../admin">Admin Login</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Project</th>
        <th>Last Edit</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($data as $data){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $data["subject"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php $dir = $data['subject'];$ffs = scandir($dir); foreach($ffs as $ff){ if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){ if(strpos($ff, '.')) {} else { $ff = ucfirst($ff); echo "<a href='../subjects/" . strtolower($ff) . "'>".$ff.'</a><br>'; } } } echo '</ol>'; }?></td>
        <td><?php $path = "./" . $data["subject"]; echo date("F d Y", filemtime($path)); ?></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

There is also a subjects.txt file which contains some of the subjects, it does display fine, except for the last row.

Comment: Use `is_dir` probably?